# Sound stopped working after using HDMI

Tags: sound, hdmi

So a couple of days ago, I had my laptop hooked up to my tv via HDMI. I used pavucontrol to disable sound on my laptop and play it through the tv. I changed it back when I was done. Can't remember if I used it right away. Last night I tried to use it and it didn't work. I opened pavucontrol again and switched to the configuration tab where there had previously been a drop down menu allowing me to choose what device to output my sound through. Now there's nothing. It says no card available for configuration. When I open asoundconf-gtk it only has "PCH" and selecting that does nothing either.

Here is my output of pulseaudio -d http://pastebin.com/75SpLihg

And using the guide on the Ubuntu Wiki Pulse Audio page, I made a log http://pastebin.com/rmARXUMD

I've tried deleting the pulse folder from my home directory and restarting the server. After searching on Google, I found similar problems required me to edit /etc/pulse/client.conf and make sure autospawn is set to yes and everything is commented out with a semicolon, which it is. Tried using qasmixer to make sure sound isn't disabled. Nothing works.
.
I've tried posting on the Ubuntu-Forums.org site and got no help there so I'm trying here because I dont want to reboot into Win7 to stream videos or listen to my mp3s.

Since I don't have reputation for more links, I'll post in the comments for my client and daemon conf files.

Running Lubuntu 12.10 with kernel 3.5.0-24-generic. I hope this is enough info.

**Edit: July 29th/13:** I decided to create a new user account and everything shows up as normal in pavucontrol. I am able to see the sound card and adjust settings although I didn't actually test the sound. So this appears to be a user configuration error (although if I run gksudo pavucontrol, I still cant access the sound card). I've deleted ~/.pulse as well as the pulse in ~/.config. Still nothing. Not sure what else to delete.

Comment: Here is the client.conf http://pastebin.com/ahWxXB5X

Here is the daemon.conf http://pastebin.com/gRyCsjdb

Comment: And here is pulse syslog http://pastebin.com/ySgnNmEb I assume it can't find the files because I deleted the pulse folder from /tmp?

Comment: check this out this should solve the problem https://askubuntu.com/a/1057780

Answer (score 32):

Well, this worked for me and it is really easy :

1. Open PulseAudio Volume Control (open a terminal and type pavucontrol).
   Install it if you don't have it.
2. When you open it, go to "Configuration" : For one of the "built in audios" one has HDMI (unplugged) in front of "Profile". **Choose "Off" for that profile**.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, can this be logged as a bug? (18.04) Thanks for your help nevertheless

Answer (score 7):

For Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Start playing music or whatever you want. (You still hear nothing)

**pavucontrol**

Go at: *playback*

You will see there that the playback for the app is set to HDMI. Redirect it.

This implies that each app might need to be manually changed :-/

Other solution, replug HDMI and choose the correct output device.

UBUNTU, you need to fix this!

Answer (score 4):

I've finally solved it. I deleted any asoundconf files from my home directory after testing the new user theory. Then I just killed and restarted pulseaudio and everything came back!

Comment: Just to add to this answer, my solution (Yes, I had this problem on Ubuntu 15.04) was to delete `~/.config/pulse` (actually I renamed it, just in case) and then start pulseaudio again using `pulseaudio -D`.

Comment: Deleting `~/.config/pulse` works for Ubuntu 18.04. restarting pulseaudio with `pulseaudio -D` does not, but logging out and then back in does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall pulseaudio with **sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio** and then reinstalling it again.

Comment: That was my last idea. I was just hoping there would be something else. I did that and restarted pulseaudio but it didn't work. The only other idea I have is to just reboot.

Comment: Try changing the /etc/pulse/client.conf to:
default-sink = alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo

Comment: No luck there either :(

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.
Plug your HDMI again and choose the right output from sound in your settings.