# Ubuntu 18.04 sound output not changed properly for applications after HDMI cable plug and unplug

Tags: sound, alsa, hdmi

I noticed the audio doesn't work for Chrome or VLC apps after unplugging the HDMI cable from my TV. The system audio like the terminal bips works fine. Only the applications can't output the audio.

I installed pavucontrol and noticed the issue was coming from the output device not set properly on built in audio in the playback tab.

I think there is a bug when the audio output switch from HDMI to built-in audio, is doesn't work for application. Interestingly it works well for the system audio.

Answer (score 2):

I did not had opportunity to connect back hdmi cable (I've noticed an issue while I was in travel in train), so I digged deeper

Here is solution (Ubuntu 18 LTS):

```
pulseaudio -k && rm -r ~/.config/pulse
```

Comment: It does not work in my case and it also does not look like a proper solution (at least if you don't want to kill system audio and flush all config every time the problem reoccurs...).

Comment: That worked in my case! I don't even have a pulseaudio systemctl daemon. I updated to 20.04 LTS and started running into a problem where my audio would not switch to headphones or bluetooth... it only played audio on my HDMI monitor :/

Answer (score 0):

Try reconnecting the HDMI, then go to sound settings. Select Built-in-audio, once it plays sound on the machine, just unplug the HDMI and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks, I didn't manage to reproduce the issue recently.