# Ubuntu OS sounds working but media sounds are not after using hdmi

Tags: sound, hdmi

The sound of media on my laptop is not working across all programs (youtube in chromium, vlc, etc). However, the clicking sounds that occur as I change the volume DO work as does the "test speakers" button in the sound menu.

This regardless of what the sound output channel is set to in settings: speakers or headphones.

The issue started after connecting my laptop to hdmi, and redirecting my sound to hdmi. I no longer have access to the hdmi screen so I can't connect to it again for testing.

Anyone know what could cause this or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you try going into the speaker options and selecting the normal output?

Comment: It is the normal output

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/662102) and let me know if it works; it's discussed [here](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/) as well (Solution 3).